# How to retrieve all related models in a many to many relationship Laravel?

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, relationship

I am trying to retrieve all related models with another model through an intermediary table but can't figure out how. The Laravel docs say you can do something like this:

```
$roles = App\User::find(1)->roles()->orderBy('name')->get();
```

But when I try to apply that to my code

```
$roles = User::where('id', $user->id)->roles()->get();
```

It does not work. I am accepting the user model through my controller, so I do have access to it.

The relationship is also defined like so:

`User`

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

`Role`

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

How can I get all of the roles associated with a particular user?

edit/update:
I know I can simply use a foreach loop and get all of the roles associated with a particular user, but I am trying to return a resource collection, so I cannot do it that way

Comment: try change `get()` for `first()`

Comment: I get an error, `undefined method roles`

Comment: @hoolakoola I think your relationship between roles and user is not correct.

Comment: In common usage, `Role`'s relationship with users will be *`$this->hasMany(User::class);`*, and also you can get the relation by simple doing _`User::find($id)->roles;`_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,
I am assuming that $user_id is the parameter which is passed into the controller from the URL,

> $roles=User::findOrFail($user_id)->roles;

But before running the above code, I assume that you have created the pivot table for many to many relationship with columns user_id and role_id. And have named the pivot table as role_user.

Hope this works

Answer (score 1):

the problem with your second approach is calling `roles()` function on an 'Eloquent Query Builder' instance. You need to make sure to call `roles()` function on a 'User Model'.

this part of code `User::where('id', $user->id)` **doesn't** return a 'User Model'.

To get an 'User Model' from a 'Query Builder' instance you need to call `first()` function.

possible solution.

```
$roles = User::where('id', $user->id)->first()->roles;
```

Comment: This answer has the most details needed. And anyway, _`User::where('id', $user->id)->first()`_ can just be simplified to _`User::find($id)`_

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you're getting the errors, is because before calling the method `first()` (or `find()` or `findOrFail()`), the instance is a `QueryBuilder`. and the `roles()` method exist only on an `User::class` instance.

if you are trying to get the `user` with an attribute `roles` containing a collection (array) of all his roles do:

```
$user = User::where('id', $user->id)->with('roles')->first();
```

if you need just the array of roles, you have two choices;
either get the user and then get his roles:

```
$user = App\User::find($userId);
$roles = $user->roles()->orderBy('name')->get();
//the same as
$roles = App\User::find($userId)->roles()->orderBy('name')->get();
```

or get the Roles (only one query)

```
$roles = Role::whereHas('users', function($users) use($userId) {
    $users->where('id','=',$userId);
})->get();
```

Hope this gives you enough insight to build the exact code you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution to retrieve all related models in a many to many relationship in Laravel:

```
$roles = User::where('id', $user->id)->get();
 foreach($roles as $rol){
  $rol->roles;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

User

```
use App\User;
public function roles()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Users', 'user_id');
}
```

Role

```
use App\Roles;
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Roles');
}
```

Controller

```
$roles = User::where('id', $user->id)->roles()->get();
```

Try this one. I think your relationship is not correct.

You can read more information here [Many To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)